# Is there any way to display an object attribute in a dialogue box in DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors

I am at my wits end, after days of searching I just can't find a way to display an attribute(with OLE) in my dialogue box I have found the following snippet but to no avail, nothing gets displayed. I really don't know if this code is going to work (or if it is even used for this purpose) but it's the closest thing I found to my requirement.

```
DB dtbox  = create "Test Window"
Module m = current Module
Object obj
void repaint(DBE canv) {}
expectedResults = canvas(dtbox,600,250,repaint)
for obj in m do {
    if (obj."Object Heading" "" != "")
    {
        if (!null getCanvas) font(getCanvas, level(obj), HeadingsFont)
        displayRich(number(obj) " " obj."Object Heading" "")
    }

    if (obj."Object Text" "" != "")
    {
        if (!null getCanvas) font(getCanvas, level(obj), TextFont)
        displayRich(richTextWithOle(obj."Object Text"))
    }
    ...
    //block until user clicks the next button

}
show dtbox
```

Answer (score 0):

A canvas is for drawing graphics or loading bitmaps, it will not display your OLE. You need to use a richText box.

```
DB dtbox  = create "Test Window"
Module m = current Module
Object obj
DBE expectedResults = richText(dtbox, "My OLE BOX", "", 600, 250, true) 
for obj in m do {
  if (obj."Object Heading" "" != "")
  {
    set(expectedResults, number(obj) " " obj."Object Heading" "")
  }

  if (obj."Object Text" "" != "")
  {
    set(expectedResults, richTextWithOle(obj."Object Text"))
  }
  ...
  //block until user clicks the next button

}
show dtbox
```

If you want to test it, just comment out the for loop and set `obj = current`. That will allow you to see it work on one specific Object.

Good luck!